# Marble Testing an asynchronous generator

Tags: rxjs

I have got a problem leveraging marble testing for testing an observable. When using a synchronous observable it works just as expected:

```js
// -------------------- SYNC (WORKS) ----------------------------
const syn = from([1, 2]);

scheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
    // -- act / assert
    expectObservable(syn).toBe('(ab|)', { a: 1, b: 2 });
});
// --------------------------------------------------------------
```

When using a asynchronous observable it works just as expected as well:

```js
// -------------------- ASYNC (WORKS) ---------------------------
const asyn = interval(100).pipe(map(idx => idx + 1), take(2));

scheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
    // -- act / assert
    expectObservable(asyn).toBe('100ms a 99ms (b|)', { a: 1, b: 2 });
});
// --------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when using an observable created from an asynchronous generator,
expectObservable returns that no value was actually emitted:

```js
// ------------- GEN (expectObservable receives []), ------------
const gen = from((async function* () {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
})());

scheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
    // -- act / assert
    expectObservable(gen).toBe('100ms a 99ms (b|)', { a: 1, b: 2 });
});
// --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why is that?